# Need help in adapting the performance testing tool to do some basic performance checks

Tags: performance, performance-testing

Could anyone please suggest the tool that is best suitable to check the performance of the application/website to do the following:

> Login and Log out of the website( This is to check, how long the site takes to load the page after login)
>   Perform Search Operation ( This is to check, how long the website takes to load the results of a search operation)
>   Open a folder(This is to check, how long the website takes to open a folder within the website)

This stats will be used by the developers to see how the website is impacted and what can be done about to increase the performance.

Just to give a bit of background, our project deals with a huge amount of data that is processed on a daily basis. This is affecting the performance of our application.

I am currently using 'iMacros' tool to do the basic performance tests which is up for renewal sometime soon.
I am looking for a free tool that performs better than iMacros.

Kind Regards,
Asha

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use the server's logs (that have timestamps for each request/response)?

Comment: I am not a technical person. Just moved into testing newly. Had a look at what Server's log means. I realized that it captures the list of activities performed in the log file. And the web static software makes it available in the readable format. But i was looking to automate the activities like " Login and Log out" repeatedly for the whole day and capture the time it takes for every login graphically. Could you please let me know if this can be achieved from the 'Server Logs'?- user:1482455

Comment: You can use a transaction monitor at Pingometer (http://pingometer.com) for this. We use one to login to our dashboard, click a link, type into a text field, click a submit button, and ensure that the resulting page has specific content.

Comment: My advise to you (very generally): if you are doing testing, then you HAVE to be a technical person. Otherwise you are going to be stuck.

Comment: Pingometer seems to be a paid tool. I am looking for something freely available to download and use.

Comment: Yephick - Thanks for your advice. I am piking up on testing domain. In the process i had to assess a free tool that creates reports showing the timestamps  and the amount of time the application takes to load the page between every login and logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not Apache JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/)? It is quite flexible and I confident you'll be able to accomplish what you have described using this.

It is likely to be free to use (offered under [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)).

Comment: JMeter looks promising. Recording test in JMeter could be of my help. I am having trouble in installing JMeter. Would you mind assisting please?

Comment: You have to tell what the problem is. And please vote if you liked the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are three different things you can do, depending on your preferences:

1. Performance testing using synthetic transactions. Here you can use a variety of tools. Selenium might be a good choice - it lets you automate real browsers. Transaction monitors like the Pingometer one mentioned can also be used but if they are meant primarily for uptime monitoring they might not be ideal for performance testing.
2. Load testing. Someone mentioned Jmeter, which is a load testing tool. With load testing you create a specific amount of synthetic transactions, to see how your site/app behaves under load. From your question I am not sure this is what you want though.
3. Performance monitoring. Looking at your existing server log files is the fastest way to do this, but they can be hard to interpret and you get more power if you use a real performance monitoring tool such as e.g. New Relic. Performance monitoring lets you see how your actual users experiences the performance of your site/app, but doesn't allow you to control which actions are tested (#1 above) or testing when there is an extraordinary amount of traffic on the site/app (#2 above).

Comment: Thanks for that. I would not prefer Selenium as it requires some knowledge on coding languages like Java... However when i choose to look at the server logs, i should be able to see the repeated actions like Login and Logout for more than 1000 times in a day(Which has to be automated) correct!? I need to know if there a tool that automates for me and also provides the report showing the timestamps and the amount of time the application takes to login everytime! Is there a tool that does both?.. Kindly let me know.